# Azure API for Java

Tags: java, azure, virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk, azure-java-tools

Tell me please, how can I get all options for instance on Azure using Java ?

For example, I mean all VM parameters: ***name, instance type, launch time and etc.***
So that I can use them in my code and get a detailed message in case of all kinds of errors associated with the VM on Azure.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Azure virtual machine libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-java-stable) to manage your virtual machines.

To use Azure management library, firstly, you need to get authenticated. For more details, you may refer to: [Authentication in Azure Management Libraries for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md#authentication-in-azure-management-libraries-for-java)

---

Another way is to use [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get). Here is the tutorial for your getting started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

You can use HttpClient or You can also directly try that API on the page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, then this is all the parameters for the Virtual Machine: subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, vmName, $expand, api-version ?

Comment: Yes. `/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}` is the resource ID. And `api-version` is used for specifying the target api  version. `$expand` is optional.